# Set builder notation for addition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Since addition is a binary operation, I would presume it is also a binary relation. If so, that makes it a subset of some $X \times Y$, i.e., a Cartesian product. How could I represent $2 + 2$ in set notation?

Comment: I would not presume so. Rather, addition is a ternary relation (namely, a relation between first summand, second summand, and sum)

Comment: Your last sentence asks about _one value_ of addition. It would be like saying "$<$ is a binary relation; which set is $2<3$?" So you're really asking for $4$ (or in that alternative example, "true" ($\top$)) as a set.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:X \to Y$ can be represented as a subset of $X \times Y$. The addition (lets say in the real numbers) is a function $+:\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, which means its a subset of $(\Bbb R \times \Bbb R) \times  \Bbb R$.

So $2+2=4$ can be written as $((2,2),4) \in +$.

Comment: In set comprehension form?

Comment: @147pm - in "set comprehension form" you define a set. For the set $\mathbb N$ of *naturals* we have that: $\text {Sum} = \{ ((x,y),z) \mid x+y=z \} \subseteq (\mathbb N \times \mathbb N) \times \mathbb N$